# Is it possible to define a branch policy in a YAML file?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to be able to define a branch policy in a YAML file (similar to a build pipeline) and have that file checked into the repo it protects.

My google-with-bing-foo has come up with nothing about this kind of functionality so far.

I would anticipate something like the following example that I quickly threw together:

**branch-policy.yml**

```
branches:
- 'master'

reviewers:
  minimumRequiredReviewers: 2
  requestorsApproveOwnChanges: false

commentResolution:
  policyRequirement: 'Required'

mergeTypes:
- 'Basic'
- 'Squash'
- 'Rebase and fast-forward'
- 'Rebase with merge commit'

- pipelineValidation:
  displayName: 'CI Build Validation'
  pipeline: 'foobar build pippeline name'
  pathFilter: ''
  trigger: 'Automatic'
  policyRequirement: 'Required'
  buildExpiration: '12h'

- automaticReviewers
  userOrGroup: 'PR Approvers; John Doe;'
  policyRequirement: 'Required'

- automaticReviewers
  userOrGroup: 'Feature Team Supervisors;'
  policyRequirement: 'Optional'
```

In the event that something like this were available, I would expect that simply having the file present in the repo's master branch would enforce the policy defined in the yaml file.

Any changes made to the file would automatically go through the PR process and have the same audit trail that any other file in source control has.

Is there any chance that something like this is already available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible currently. Yaml file is defined for pipeline and won't run automatically unless you set the trigger. And also once the branch policy is set for a specific branch. You will not be allowed to make changes directly for this branch. All the changes that go to this branch will be via pull request.

If you donot want to set a branch policy on the GUI page, You can use restful api to set it. [official documents for configuration restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#build-policy).

You can also submit a user voice in the [microsoft developer forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).